# Spring security, тестирование MVC и заглушка для сервисов

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Пытаюсь протестировать контроллер, у которого есть `@PreAuthorize` и сервис, который надо подменить заглушкой

PlayerController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/player")
public class PlayerController {
  @Autowired
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
  public
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<List<String>> loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(playerService.getPlayers(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

PlayerServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService{
  @Autowired
  private PlayerRepo playerRepo;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<String> getPlayers()() {
    return playerRepo.findAll();
  }
}
```

Первый способ тестирования: в этом случае тест проходит, но как вы можете заметить у пользователя `authority` выставлен `SOMEONE`, поэтому тест должен падать, т.к. данный контроллер доступен только для администратора

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SOMEONE"))) //Не завалился
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(playerController)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
        .build();
}
```

Второй способ тестирования: для авторизации он работает правильно, но вот PlayerService при этом не получаеть подменить заглушкой.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player)); //Не получилось заглушить

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers(); //Вызова не было
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);  
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc.webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы можно было подменить заглушкой `PlayerService` и чтобы при этом работал `@PreAuthorize`?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите протестировать? Опишите ваши намерения словами.

Comment: что контроллер выдаёт информацию, только, когда у пользователя права администратора

Comment: иными словами, вы хотите проверить, что контроллер имеет аннотацию с правильной ролью?

Comment: Да, но ещё не забыть проверить, что функция правильно вызвала другие методы

Comment: эта функция - контроллер?

Comment: метод контроллера в этом случае `loadByAdmin()`

Comment: если вы пишите юнит тест, то то должна быть одна проверка на тест! те есть вам надо написать 2 теста в одном проверять наличие аннотации, а в другом проверять что контроллер вызвал сервис.

Comment: Ну хорошо, но если мы проверяем авторизацию, то `PlayerService` вызывается, а нам нужно освободить его от этих бессмысленных действий, а мы не можем это сделать, т.к. у нас нет контроля над ним

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, можно через рефлексию подсунуть заглушки в реальный контроллер

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @Autowired
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Autowired
  private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player)); //получилось заглушить

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers(); //Вызов состоялся
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);  
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(playerController)
        .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(playerController, "playerService", playerService);
}
```